# Child theme not displaying footer navigation correctly

Tags: css, navigation, footer

I just don't understand. It worked fine at one point but not it's not working? I have a footer navigation list that I'm trying to put back together from moving it from my local server to the web server but it's not doing anything now. Not matter what or how I style it, what I call it or what I do it's not working. I'm using firebug to work on it but I just can't find the problem.

This is my HTML

```
<div id="footerbottom">
    <ul class="foot-navigation">
        <li>Home</li>   
        <li>Home</li>   
        <li>Home</li>   
        <li>Home</li>   
        <li>Home</li>   
    </ul>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#footerbottom { width: 100%; height: 93px; background: url(../img/FOOTER-BG-bottom.jpg) repeat; background-color: #252525; color: #fff; margin-top: -30px; 
#footerbottom p { width: 600px; margin-left: 370px; height: 30px; font-size: 1em; line-height: 25px; color: #eee; margin-top: 40px; position: absolute;left: 50%; margin-left: -470px; }

.foot-navigation { width: 900px; height: 30px; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 1em; letter-spacing: 1px; list-style:none;  position:relative; margin 10px auto; }
.foot-navigation li { float: left; margin-right: 15px; }
.foot-navigation li a { text-decoration: none; color: #fff; }
.foot-navigation li a:hover { color: #d80800; }
```

[image]

I'm creating a child theme from the TwentyTen theme and so far haven't had any troubles until now. If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it. I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. [The site is here](http://fhlsociety.ca) if you want to look at it.

Comment: I don't understand clearly what do want to achieve...

Comment: I'm trying to style my footer navigation but with my styling but all I see is the image I uploaded. It's like my CSS is being ignored.

Comment: It's me, or there are 2 `style.css` files?

Comment: It's a child theme of Twenty Ten so there are 2

Comment: I just don't understand. I can style it all with firebug with no problem, but when it comes time to put it into my actual style.css sheet my theme just ignores it.

Comment: Please Accept "your" answer so this Question is resolved. FYI: Your http://fhlsociety.ca/wp-content/themes/fhlchild/style.css file line 218 has incorrect URL for background for #footerbottom. It should be http://www.fhlsociety.ca/img/FOOTER-BG-bottom.jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys. I've found a work around that I didn't want to do but it works so I'll do it. I'm just inserting the styles that aren't working right into the style.css sheet for the TwentyTen theme. It's the only way it's going to work. I was taught that I could import all the files of the TwentyTen theme and add my own with my own style sheet however with this case that's just not working.

Comment: Glad you did something, I ran out of ideas, maybe changing the name of the archive `style.css` for something like `site.css` could help and you can keep the class `.foot-navigation` in other file, but idk... good luck there...

Comment: Please Accept your answer so this Question is resolved. FYI: Your `http://fhlsociety.ca/wp-content/themes/fhlchild/style.css` file line 218 has incorrect URL for background for `#footerbottom`. It should be `http://www.fhlsociety.ca/img/FOOTER-BG-bottom.jpg`.

Comment: Thanks for the info arttronics

Answer (score 0):

your `foot-navigation` isn't getting any style. Please check it and your ul has a class of `foot-navigation`, from where you are getting `.foot-navigation ul`?

Comment: I even try to put a border around anything in the footer navigation and it doesn't show up, so something is over writing it but I have no clue what.